# Facing issues while updating the property value in polymer JS

Tags: polymer, polymer-2.x

I'm creating a very simple CRUD app using Polymer js but facing some issues while editing the records.

Here is the code for add/edit:

```
        _addTodo() {
            if(this.user.id) {
                let foundIndex = this.users.findIndex( x => x.id === this.user.id);
                this.users[foundIndex] = this.user;

                this.set('users', this.users);

                console.log(this.users);
            }
            else {
                this.user.id = Math.floor((Math.random() * 100000) + 1);
                this.push('users', this.user);
            }
            this.user = {};
        }
```

Although I could see the values inside the users object getting changed in the browser console but it's not getting changed in the DOM/UI.

If I'm using a static user object like below then it works:

```
        _addTodo() {
            if(this.user.id) {

                var users = [
                        {
                            id: 1,
                            name: 'xyz',
                            age: 21
                        },
                        {
                            id: 2,
                            name: 'xyz123',
                            age: 5
                        }
                    ]

                this.set('users', users);

                console.log(this.users);
            }
            else {
                this.user.id = Math.floor((Math.random() * 100000) + 1);
                this.push('users', this.user);
            }
            this.user = {};
        }
```

Even I have used "notifyPath" instead of "set" but that is also not working.

Could anyone please suggest what I am doing wrong here for which the user object is not getting changed in DOM?

Update:

As suggested below, I'm using splice for updating the array but still it's not working.

JSfiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/ansumanmishra/8490y4q8/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
>    this.users[foundIndex] = this.user;
>
>    this.set('users', this.users);
> ```

Updating the DOM takes performance. Whenever `set` is used, Polymer dirty checks every value in the array, but you have already set the array to it's new value so when it compares (basically, it compares with itself), Polymer wont detect any updates and therefor wont update the DOM.

You can't however do this as solution: `var newUserArr = this.users`, and then modify `newUserArr` because objects and arrays only create references to each other.

```
var a = [1]
var b = a

b[0] = 2

console.log(a) // gives [2]
```

You will only end up with the same thing as above: Polymer dirty checking the array with itself. Remove the reference with JSON.stringify, and then set the new array. I use this method all the time.

```
        if(this.user.id) {
            let foundIndex = this.users.findIndex( x => x.id === this.user.id);

              // Remove references
            var newUserArr = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.users)));

            newUserArr[foundIndex] = this.user;

            this.set('users', newUserArr);
        }
```

---

EDIT

However, when you want to edit something, you *also* create a reference from the object in the array, so when you type in your inputs, you will update the object in the existing array `users`.

I fiddled with your fiddle, and now it works. What I did was that I added `JSON.parse(JSON.stringify())` in the method `_editUser()` too.

http://jsfiddle.net/c6h2hwch/

Comment: It's still not working as expected. Here is the link to JSfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/8490y4q8/3/

Comment: You're using two-way binding and updating the reference to the object in the array. You need to remove that reference too:
CHANGE
`this.set('user', userArr[0]);`
TO
`this.set('user', JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(userArr[0])));`

I'm updating my answer

Answer (score 0):

From ["Set a property or subproperty by path"](https://www.polymer-project.org/2.0/docs/devguide/model-data#set-path): "calling set on an object property won't cause Polymer to pick up changes to the object's subproperties, unless the object itself changes." Note example:

```
// DOES NOT WORK
this.profile.name = Alex;
this.set('profile', this.profile);
```

You need to replace `this.profile` with a new `profile` object, or update the path of each individual member of `profile`.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't an observable change:

```
this.users[foundIndex] = this.user;
this.set('users', this.users);
```

You're modifying the array that `this.users` points to (in a way Polymer can't detect) and then setting `this.users` to the same array—`this.set('users', this.users)` is the same operation as `this.users = this.users`.

You have a couple options. One is to use [`this.splice`](https://www.polymer-project.org/2.0/docs/devguide/model-data#array-mutation):

```
this.splice('users', foundIndex, 1, this.user);
```

This says, "remove `1` item at `foundIndex` and insert `this.user` in its place.

The other option is to create a copy of the array (with `Array.prototype.slice`—note that's [`slice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice), not `splice`) to make the change observable:

```
const nextUsers = this.users.slice();
nextUsers[foundIndex] = this.user;
this.users = nextUsers;
```

I recommend `this.splice` because it doesn't make Polymer do quite as much work when re-rendering e.g. a `dom-repeat` for the array.

Comment: Still not working after doing this:     
if(this.user.id) {
    let foundIndex = this.users.findIndex( x => x.id === this.user.id);
     
   this.splice('users', foundIndex, 1, this.user);
   }

Anything I am missing out here?

Comment: Can you please take a look into the example above and suggest? Used Splice but still it's not working